# EF Core 2.0 Generic DbSet does not have method AsNoTracking

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to implement a Generic repository as described in 
https://codingblast.com/entity-framework-core-generic-repository/

It seems the generic DbSet does not have implemention for method AsNoTracking( ), am i not using the correct syntax? How to fix this issue

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
    }

   }
```

Comment: `AsNoTracking` is *extension* method and requires `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`. But `DbContext` is defined in the same namespace, so the method in question should be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix here.
`AsNoTracking` method only configures query in a way that once it gets enumerated it won't track changes on those entities.
This is useful when you are doing read only and will not do any editing in that procedure. It is done for speed and efficiency.
So the method has no functionality that can be Async.

You will use Async methods when enumerating query, like:
`ToListAsync()` or
`SingleOrDefaultAsync()`